# Formula keyboard ios

Tags: ios, xcode

my application is a maths application, and I would like a sort of formula keyboard to appear besides the normal ios keyboard. The ios keyboard on ipad gives numbers, but not square roots and other maths formats, so is there an already existing api i can use for this purpose? Thanks for any ideas

Comment: Why don't you try for custom keyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find these superb links that will help you to create custom keyboard.

Few have many different formats of keyboard with running applications, you can simply modify them according to your need.

http://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=keyboard

http://code.google.com/p/networkpx/wiki/Using_5RowQWERTY

https://github.com/vikingosegundo/KeyPad

http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tutorials/7350-adding-subviews-custimize-keyboard.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, text fields and text views provide `inputView` and `inputAccessoryView` properties you can use to customise the keyboards used for them.